# Matchstick Riddle

Tags: riddle, matches

Disclaimer: This is a matchstick riddle, not puzzle. Oh, and everything is a clue.

[image: matchstick equation equal to '19 = 94']

Only enter an answer if: **it** is **original**. Then, you can **release** the answer you think it is.

Comment: Would any of [[tag:visual]], [[tag:enigmatic-puzzle]], or [[tag:stenography]] apply here?

Comment: If this weren't a [riddle], I would do [19 = 19](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jMZA8.png) :)

Comment: @riskymysteries: that could still qualify as a minor riddle: *where did the two unnecessary matchsticks go/ get double-placed?*

Comment: @smci in risky's answer there is no unnecessary matchstick, just that the 9 is represented differently.

Comment: @justhalf: I know, or equivalently you can hide the bottom-segment in both 9's by laying it on any other matchstick, and conform to standard 7-segment format.

Comment: Ah, ok, I misunderstood your comment.

Comment: Pay attention to the words I used. Huge clue: the bold words.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is: (Drumroll please)

> 1990

Explanation:

> The **original** movie **It** was **released** in 1990. You can make the matchbox thing say 1990 if you use the 2 sticks in the equal sign and the existing 4 in the 4. It would look like [image: this]

Comment: Great Job! I thought I made it too complicated...

Comment: @AkshayaGunnam At first I did not understand the question then I solved it pretty easily.

Comment: What does "it waste released" mean? Which movie?

Comment: I think you mean: the movie 'It' was released in 1990. Actually it was a TV miniseries. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/It_%28miniseries%29

Comment: @DrD My bad I meant was